# Каким образом в Python можно организовать паузу и возобновление работы функции?

Tags: python

написал код, дающий работать только одной из четырёх функций, но столкнулся с рядом проблем: функции не возобновляются в том же месте, где были остановлены, также они не работают заявленное время

```
    import _thread
import timeit
import random
import time
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep
l=_thread.allocate_lock()
m=_thread.allocate_lock()

def P1():
    a = timeit.default_timer()
    while (timeit.default_timer() - a < 15):
        if ((not l.locked())&(not m.locked())):
            print(('P1'))
            sleep(1)
def P2():
    a = timeit.default_timer()
    while (timeit.default_timer() - a < 9):
        if ((not l.locked())&(m.locked())):
            print(('P2'))
            sleep(1)
def P3():
    a = timeit.default_timer()
    while (timeit.default_timer() - a < 13):
        if ((l.locked())&(not m.locked())):
            print(('P3'))
            sleep(1)
def P4():
    a = timeit.default_timer()
    while (timeit.default_timer() - a < 12):
        if ((l.locked())&(m.locked())):
            print(('P4'))
            sleep(1)
def start(P):
    _thread.start_new_thread(P, ())

_thread.start_new_thread(P1,())
sleep(1)
_thread.start_new_thread(P2,())
_thread.start_new_thread(P3,())
_thread.start_new_thread(P4,())
sleep(2)
for i in range(3):
    l.acquire()
    sleep(1.5)
    m.acquire()
    sleep(1.5)
    l.release()
    sleep(1.5)
input()
```

Comment: Опишите подробно, какое поведение вы ожидаете от вашего скрипта.

Comment: остановка выполнения функции по таймеру, после чего продолжение выполнения с того места, где произошла остановка.

Answer (score 1):

Если функции должны выполняться только по очереди, и параллельное выполнение не нужно, то я бы рекомендовал не заморачиваться с потоками.

Я бы решил эту задачу примерно так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now
from time import sleep

from itertools import cycle, starmap

from collections import namedtuple


class Manager:
  """ Класс, который управляет очерёдностью """

  def __init__(self, func_list, shedule):
    workers = [Worker(func) for func in func_list]
    Task = namedtuple('SheduleElement', ['worker', 'duration'])
    self.shedule = cycle(starmap(Task, zip(workers, shedule)))

  def run(self):
    while True:
      task = next(self.shedule)
      start_time = now()
      end_time = start_time + timedelta(seconds=task.duration)
      task.worker.run(end_time=end_time)
      print('* Запускаю следующую функцию!')


class Worker:

  def __init__(self, func):
    self.job = func()

  def run(self, end_time):
    while now() < end_time:
      next(self.job)


# Конец основного кода
# Ниже идёт тестовый пример


def P1():
  count = 0
  while True:
    count += 1
    print('P1', count)
    sleep(1)
    yield

def P2():
  count = 0
  while True:
    count += 1
    print('P2', count)
    sleep(1)
    yield

def P3():
  count = 0
  while True:
    count += 1
    print('P3', count)
    sleep(1)
    yield

def P4():
  count = 0
  while True:
    count += 1
    print('P4', count)
    sleep(1)
    yield

func_list = [P1, P2, P3, P4]
shedule = [3, 2, 5, 1]  # Время, которое выделено каждой функции (в секундах)
manager = Manager(func_list, shedule)

manager.run()
```

Если вы запустите пример, то увидите, что функции сохраняют своё состояние между вызовами. Это достигается за счёт использования ключевого слова `yield` вместо `return`.

Если вы воспользуетесь этим скриптом, то любые ваши функции для поочередного выполнения нужно строить по тому же принципу - бесконечный цикл внутри которого есть слово `yield`